# JavaScript calculator for FCC

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a JavaScript calculator as a Freecodecamp frontend project. Here are mine .html and .js files. Your help or advices are welcome. Task objective: Build a CodePen.io app that is functionally similar to [this](https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/rLJZrA/).

Fulfill the below user stories. Use whichever libraries or APIs you need. Give it your own personal style.

User Story: I can add, subtract, multiply and divide two numbers.

User Story: I can clear the input field with a clear button.

User Story: I can keep chaining mathematical operations together until I hit the equal button, and the calculator will tell me the correct output.

Remember to use Read-Search-Ask if you get stuck.

When you are finished, click the "I've completed this challenge" button and include a link to your CodePen.

You can get feedback on your project by sharing it with your friends on Facebook.

```
<div class="container" align=center>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 well">
    <p class="title">JAVASCRIPT CALCULATOR</p>
    <table >
      <tr height=60 class="screen-row">
        <td><h1 id="demo" class="screen-content">0</h1></td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=20 class="screen-row">
        <td><p id="demo2" class="screen-content">0</p></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr height=30>
        <td><button onclick="key7()">7</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="key8()">8</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="key9()">9</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="funcDiv()">/</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=30>
        <td><button onclick="key4()">4</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="key5()">5</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="key6()">6</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="funcMultiply()">x</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=30>
        <td><button onclick="key1()">1</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="key2()">2</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="key3()">3</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="funcSub()">-</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=30>
        <td colspan="2"><button onclick="key0()">0</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="funcDot()">,</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="funcAdd()">+</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr height=30>
        <td colspan="2"><button onclick="funcClear()">clear</button></td>
        <td colspan="2"><button onclick="funcTotal()">=</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript part:

```
var number = "",
    temp = "",
    total = 0,
    arr = [],
    arrShow = [],
    arrTemp = [],
    dotOn = false;;

function funcClear() {
    number = "";
    temp = "";
    arr = [];
    dotOn = false;
    arrShow = [];
    arrTemp = [];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 0;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 0;
}
function funcReset() {
    setTimeout(function(){ funcClear(); }, 3000);
}
function funcTotal() {
    if (number) {
        arr.push(number);
        arrShow.push(number);
        number = "";
    } else {
        arr.pop();
    }

    total = arr.splice(0,1);

    while (arr.length > 0) {
        arrTemp = arr.splice(0, 2);
        if (arrTemp[0] == '-') {total = (1*total) - (1*arrTemp[1]);}
        if (arrTemp[0] == '+') {total = (1*total) + (1*arrTemp[1]);}
        if (arrTemp[0] == '/') {total = (1*total) / (1*arrTemp[1]);}
        if (arrTemp[0] == '*') {total = (1*total) * (1*arrTemp[1]);}
        total = (Math.round(total * 100) / 100);
        var totalStr = total.toString();
        if (totalStr.length < 12) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Too big number";
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Resetting in 3 seconds...";
            funcReset();
        }
    }
    number = (Math.round(total * 100) / 100);
    temp = "";
    arr = [];
    dotOn = false;
    arrShow = [];
    arrTemp = [];
}
function funcSub() {
    if (number) {
        arr.push(number);
        arr.push('-');
        arrShow.push(number);
        arrShow.push('-');
        temp = number;
        number = "";
        dotOn = false;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "-";
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
    }
}
function funcAdd() {
    if (number) {
        arr.push(number);
        arr.push('+');
        arrShow.push(number);
        arrShow.push('+');
        temp = number;
        number = "";
        dotOn = false;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "+";
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
    }
}
function funcDiv() {
    if (number) {
        arr.push(number);
        arr.push('/');
        arrShow.push(number);
        arrShow.push('/');
        temp = number;
        number = "";
        dotOn = false;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "/";
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
    }
}
function funcMultiply() {
    if (number) {
        arr.push(number);
        arr.push('*');
        arrShow.push(number);
        arrShow.push('*');
        temp = number;
        number = "";
        dotOn = false;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "*";
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
    }
}
function funcDot() {
    if (number) {
        if (!dotOn) {
            dotOn = true;
            number = number.concat(".");
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
            if (arrShow.length > 0) {
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
            } else {
                document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
function key0() {
    if (number.length < 8) {
        number = number.concat("0");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
        if (arrShow.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 0;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Number limit reached";
    }
}
function key1() {
    if (number.length < 8) {
        number = number.concat("1");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
        if (arrShow.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 0;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Number limit reached";
    }
}
function key2() {
    if (number.length < 8) {
        number = number.concat("2");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
        if (arrShow.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 0;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Number limit reached";
    }
}
function key3() {
    if (number.length < 8) {
        number = number.concat("3");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
        if (arrShow.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 0;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Number limit reached";
    }
}
function key4() {
    if (number.length < 8) {
        number = number.concat("4");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
        if (arrShow.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 0;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Number limit reached";
    }
}
function key5() {
    if (number.length < 8) {
        number = number.concat("5");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
        if (arrShow.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 0;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Number limit reached";
    }
}
function key6() {
    if (number.length < 8) {
        number = number.concat("6");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
        if (arrShow.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 0;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Number limit reached";
    }
}
function key7() {
    if (number.length < 8) {
        number = number.concat("7");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
        if (arrShow.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
          } else {
              document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 0;
          }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Number limit reached";
    }
}
function key8() {
    if (number.length < 8) {
        number = number.concat("8");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
        if (arrShow.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
          } else {
              document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 0;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Number limit reached";
    }
}
function key9() {
    if (number.length < 8) {
        number = number.concat("9");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
        if (arrShow.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = arrShow.join(' ');
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = 0;
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Number limit reached";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there are many elements with similar logic you can use this approach:

```js
var number = "",
  total = 0,
  regexp = /[0-9]/,
  mainScreen = document.getElementById("mainScreen");

function InputSymbol(num) {
  var cur = document.getElementById(num).value;
  var prev = number.slice(-1);
  // Do not allow 2 math operators in row
  if (!regexp.test(prev) && !regexp.test(cur)) {
    console.log("Two math operators not allowed after each other ;)");
    return;
  }
  number = number.concat(cur);
  mainScreen.innerHTML = number;
}

function CalculateTotal() {
  // Time for some EVAL magic
  total = (Math.round(eval(number) * 100) / 100);
  mainScreen.innerHTML = total;
}

function DeleteLastSymbol() {
  if (number) {
    number = number.slice(0, -1);
    mainScreen.innerHTML = number;
  }
  if (number.length === 0) {
    mainScreen.innerHTML = "0";
  }
}

function ClearScreen() {
  number = "";
  mainScreen.innerHTML = 0;
}
```

```css
body, div, header, h1, p, table, tr, td {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

header {
    letter-spacing: 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
}

button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 400px;
    background-color: silver;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.screen {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #2d2929;
    color: white;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>JAVASCRIPT CALCULATOR</header>
    <div class="screen">
      <h1 id="mainScreen">0</h1>
    </div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><button value="7" id="7" onclick="InputSymbol(7)">7</button></td>
        <td><button value="8" id="8" onclick="InputSymbol(8)">8</button></td>
        <td><button value="9" id="9" onclick="InputSymbol(9)">9</button></td>
        <td><button onclick="DeleteLastSymbol()">c</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button value="4" id="4" onclick="InputSymbol(4)">4</button></td>
        <td><button value="5" id="5" onclick="InputSymbol(5)">5</button></td>
        <td><button value="6" id="6" onclick="InputSymbol(6)">6</button></td>
        <td><button value="/" id="104" onclick="InputSymbol(104)">/</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button value="1" id="1" onclick="InputSymbol(1)">1</button></td>
        <td><button value="2" id="2" onclick="InputSymbol(2)">2</button></td>
        <td><button value="3" id="3" onclick="InputSymbol(3)">3</button></td>
        <td><button value="*" id="103" onclick="InputSymbol(103)">*</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button value="0" id="0" onclick="InputSymbol(0)">0</button></td>
        <td><button value="-" id="102" onclick="InputSymbol(102)">-</button></td>
        <td><button value="+" id="101" onclick="InputSymbol(101)">+</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button onclick="ClearScreen()">clear</button></td>
        <td colspan="2"><button onclick="CalculateTotal()">=</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```